# Why is the Apache Pid File undefined?

Tags: apache

when i try to start, stop or restart my WebServer on a Debian vServer it says: "**ERROR: APACHE_PID_FILE needs to be defined in /etc/apache2/envvars**"!
Why is that and how can i repair it?

Thanks for all answers!

Answer (score 0):

It means you're meant to invoke the startup through the provided apachectl script, or through "service".

Comment: If i use service the Error in my first Message will appear. If i type "apache2ctl restart" it shows me another Error.